# Seaborn Plot doesn't show up

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating a bar chart with seaborn, and it's not generating any sort of error, but nothing happens either.

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas 
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

data = pandas.read_csv('fy15crime.csv', low_memory = False)
seaborn.countplot(x="primary_type", data=data)
plt.xlabel('crime')
plt.ylabel('amount')

seaborn.plt.show()
```

I added "seaborn.plt.show() in an effort to have it show up, but it isn't working still.

Answer (score 8):

You should place this line somewhere in the top `cell` in Jupyter to enable inline plotting:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simply `plt.show()` you were close. No need for `seaborn`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is still nothing showing up! If it makes any difference, I am using Anaconda as my editor

Comment: Try this [example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) `seaborn.plt.show()` or `plt.show()` worked fine for me. If that example works possibly something with the data.

Comment: Are you using ipython?

Comment: No, I'll try it in jupyter notebook

Comment: If your data is fine I'm assuming it's a `%matplotlib qt` problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using PyCharm using a standard Python file and I had the best luck with the following:

1. Move code to a Jupyter notebook (which can you do inside of PyCharm by right clicking on the project and choosing new - Jupyter Notebook)
2. If running a chart that takes a lot of processing time it might not have been obvious before, but in Jupyter mode you can easily see when the cell has finished processing.